# Laravel 5.7 - vue template won't render

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.7

I am trying to setup Laravel with Vue, but for some reason nothing is being rendered at the moment.

This is the code I have:

main layout file (**main.blade.php**)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />

        <title>Pathfinder Character Sheet</title>

        <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}"/ rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.fontawesome.com/css/fontawesome-app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id=character-sheet>
            <master></master>
        </div>
        <link rel="js" href="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}">
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js file**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Master from './components/layout/Master'

require('./bootstrap');
require('./light-bootstrap-dashboard');

window.Event = new Vue()
window.Vue   = Vue

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#character-sheet',
    components: {
        Master
    },
    template: '<Master/>',
});
```

**Master.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper" id="character-sheet">

        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt excepturi, ex exercitationem laborum beatae nostrum molestiae inventore eos amet ut debitis nam accusamus illum ipsa soluta ipsam officiis doloremque rerum.</span>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "Master"
}
</script>
```

I am not getting any error, just a blank screen (app.js file is loaded).
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: same id added in two times in dom.

Comment: Tried both combination where the id is either in the blade file or vue file, result is still the same.

Comment: Any errors in your developer console?

Comment: @Jerodev 0 errors either in PHP or JS ( this is the message I am getting when I save Master.vue - **DONE  Compiled successfully in 28ms**)

Comment: There is no need to add `<master></master>` in your app div, you have already added the Master element to the template on your Vue instance. Try removing this.

Comment: Still nothing (I removed id from the Master.vue and removed <master></master>)

Comment: Are you using [Vue dev tools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools#installation)? Maybe this can give more insight in what is going on. And you will also be able to see if the Component is actually mounted.

Comment: Didn't occur to me to check this, but the Vue dev tools are not detecting Vue instance (Vue.js not detected message). 
I am running an instance on the local server via php (php artisan server). I am not sure this is the issue, since I am loading vue from app.js.

Comment: @Jerodev - found the error - I used link for loading JS instead of script. I didn't see the forest from the tree :D.

Comment: Glad you found the error. Strange that I didn't notice that myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ***id="character-sheet"*** from Master.vue

In **app.js** use as follows.....

```
Vue.component('master', require('./components/layout/Master.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
el: '#character-sheet' });
```

Run the command: `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML Id is not quoted.

Change `<div id=character-sheet>`
To `<div id="character-sheet">`

Comment: That's perfectly valid html :)

Answer (score 0):

id must be unique, you're putting two elements with same id nested. Try not putting the component inside that tag.

```
...
<body>
  <master></master>
  <link rel="js" href="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}">
</body>
...
```